# In TSQL, I am having difficulty getting Decimal(38,15) value to show 15 points after the decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, floating-point, decimal

In some calculations, I am expecting to receive a value out to 15 decimal places but I am only getting it out to 6 decimal places.

In the example below, For @ProRata I am getting the value **0.8871340000000** when I expect **0.887134492110339**.

```
DECLARE @EligiblePurchase DECIMAL(38,15) = 0
   ,@ProRata DECIMAL(38,15) = 0                 --Percent of total purchase
   ,@Reduction DECIMAL(38,15) = 0
   ,@Denominator DECIMAL(38,15) = 355302907.06  --Total amount across all purchases
   ,@InitialValue DECIMAL(38,15) = 315201464.00 --Specific purchase

--Sometimes @Reduction will be a reduction % like 16.677777777777777, but in this case it's 0
SET @EligiblePurchase = @InitialValue * ((100.00 - @Reduction) / 100)
SET @ProRata = @EligiblePurchase / @Denominator
SELECT @ProRata
```

My google-fu is failing me. SqlServer is doing something I am not expecting.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I tested it with float and it returns the correct value, however, for this precision you should not use float. Funny behavior. Check this thread, it's a very similar problem: https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=92608

Comment: `My google-fu is failing me` - *sql server decimal division precision*, first result.

Comment: If you check the intermediate results you'll find the `scale` comes up short here: `select @EligiblePurchase / @Denominator as Value, SQL_Variant_Property( @EligiblePurchase / @Denominator, 'basetype' ) as BaseType, SQL_Variant_Property( @EligiblePurchase / @Denominator, 'precision' ) as Precision, SQL_Variant_Property( @EligiblePurchase / @Denominator, 'scale' ) as Scale;`. It's enlightening to go through step by step this way and see the data types of the intermediate values.